# Fetch data and images from the website to ListView

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm running to following code to fetch data and images from website to ListView through JSON.

Now it is showing an error for the same.

Can you assist finding the problem ?

```
        public class FoodView extends ListActivity 
        {
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;


            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

            private static String url_all_products = "http://ambrogroup.com/app/index/file/food";
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
        private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "img";
        private static final String TAG_DESTINATION = "destination";
        private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";

            JSONArray products = null;

        @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.food_view);

        //      productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();        // Hashmap for ListView
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();                                // Loading products in Background Thread by explicit function

        ListView listview = getListView();                                  // Get listview



        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {         // on seleting single product // launching Edit Product Screen
        @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                    {
                        //getting values from selected ListItem
                        String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
                        String pname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                        String pimg = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.img)).getText().toString();
                        String pdestination = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.destination)).getText().toString();
                        String pprice = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();
                    }
                });

            }

        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
        {       
            ListView listView;
            ArrayList<ItemList> listArray = new ArrayList<ItemList>();
            CustomListViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FoodView.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading list. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show(); 
                }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Getting all the list : ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) 
            {
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                String[] mStrings= new String[products.length()];
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String img = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                    String destination = c.getString(TAG_DESTINATION);
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                    mStrings[i] = img;
                    String urldisplay = mStrings[i];
                    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                      try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                               listArray.add(new ItemList(mIcon11,id,name,destination,price));

                               listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
                               customGridAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(FoodView.this, R.layout.row_grid, listArray);
                               listView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

                            }
                        } 
                        else 
                        {

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }



            }
        }
```

LOGCAT

```
04-24 05:17:35.508: W/System.err(1072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-24 05:17:35.508: W/System.err(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-24 05:17:35.558: I/Choreographer(1072): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 05:17:36.038: W/System.err(1072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-24 05:17:36.038: W/System.err(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-24 05:17:36.038: W/System.err(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 05:17:36.068: W/System.err(1072):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-24 05:17:36.068: W/dalvikvm(1072): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4afcba8)
04-24 05:17:36.138: I/Choreographer(1072): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Process: com.ambrogroup, PID: 1072
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.ambrogroup.FoodView$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(FoodView.java:136)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.ambrogroup.FoodView$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(FoodView.java:1)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-24 05:17:36.688: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: What do you do on FoodView.java line 136 ? Something is null.

Comment: you are getting this error because you are setting listview with adapter in doInBackground method..
you can use onPostExecute() for that else use runOnUiThread
hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You should not setAdapter to listview in doInBackGround() method. you can call this postExecute() in asyncTask

```
 protected String postExecute()
 {
     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
     customGridAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(FoodView.this, R.layout.row_grid, listArray);
     listView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);
 }
```

Comment: i did as you told. bust same error persist.                     04-24 05:34:15.098: W/System.err(1123):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 05:34:15.108: W/System.err(1123):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-24 05:34:15.108: E/Error(1123): Protocol not found: www.ambrogroup.com/assets/brands/foods/comingsoon.jpg
04-24 05:34:15.128: W/System.err(1123): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: www.ambrogroup.com/assets/brands/foods/comingsoon.jpg

Comment: did u commented those lines in doInBackground

Comment: use lazyloader library for getting images from server

Comment: yes i commented.. but why this error is coming  "E/Error(1123): Protocol not found: www.ambrogroup.com/assets/brands/foods/comingsoon.jpg"   even url path is fethced.

Comment: answer of the above question is to use "http://" instead of "www.". This was the reason of the error.. Thank you all you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ListView in the  class LoadAllProducts.Declare the listview of the  FoodView class before  `new LoadAllProducts().execute();`